# Highlight items in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

In my App I have a ListView, which is fed by a LinkedList. 
Some of the Elements in the List are "kind of special". which is why I want to highlight them in some kind. 
E.g. underline their names or have them differently colored. 
Does anyone know how i can achieve somthing like that?

Comment: Please show some effort before posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you could do is to make your own adapter by extending `BaseAdapter`.

Then, in `getView()`, you can check the contents of your `LinkedList` and based on that you can return an appropriate view with underlined text, different colors and so on.

here is a tutorial: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/android-listview-example-with-image-and.html